# Do I need to install VirtualBox Extension Pack and dkms?

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I haven't used virtual box for a while. I am trying to install the latest virtualbox on Ubuntu 18.04 [doesn't mention to install](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)

- VirtualBox Extension Pack and
- dkms

after installing virtualbox 5.2.

Do I need to install the two, or is it better to do so? If yes, how?

---

I have some problem installing dkms, after installing virtual box and its extension pack. How can I solve the problem?

```
$ sudo apt install virtualbox-dkms
[sudo] password for t: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package virtualbox-dkms
```

Comment: In short, yes they are required.

Comment: Thanks. (1) What else do I need to install? (2) I have some problem installing dkms. see my update.

Comment: Are your multiverse repositories enabled? You can check it using Software and updates app.

Comment: It was because I overwrote my /etc/apt/souces.list.

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository multiverse` should enable the multiverse repository so that you can install `virtualbox-dkms` if need be.

Comment: Overwritten sources, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories

Answer (score 3):

In short, no.

1. virtualbox-dkms does not reqired for deb package from oracle site
2. VirtualBox Extension Pack only need for USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 devices, VirtualBox RDP, disk encryption, NVMe and PXE boot for Intel cards

From [VirtualBox site](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), *Extension Pack* section:

> Support for USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 devices, VirtualBox RDP, disk encryption, NVMe and PXE boot for Intel cards. See this chapter from the User Manual for an introduction to this Extension Pack. The Extension Pack binaries are released under the VirtualBox Personal Use and Evaluation License (PUEL). *Please install the same version extension pack as your installed version of VirtualBox.*